# Автоматический логин за второго пользователя при входе на RDP

Tags: windows, сервер, rdp

Всем здравствуйте.
Помогите пожалуйста найти решение проблемы: необходимо сделать так, что бы при входе на RDP через отдельный аккаунт "админа", автоматически логинилась ещё одна учётка.
Это нужно для разных профилей программы.
Стоит Windows Server 2022, захожу через RDP за "Админ" и должна грузиться ещё одна учётка, в которой нужный мне второй профиль.
Может bat-ник какой можно сделать или в реестре как то пошаманить?

Comment: Вариант с командной строки: runas (пароль пробросить можно), для языков программирования есть библиотеки и функции под каждую конкретную среду (с++ с# питон и т д) свои. UAC выключен, включить програмно нельзя.

Comment: А как это сделать автоматически, что бы было? Что бы программа запускалась не в фоне, а выдавало мне окно приложения(за другого пользователя) после логина за "админа"?

Comment: И вопрос в том, что бы автоматически запускать пользователя другого, вместе с "Админ"